# TranscationScope is not producing lock on sql table from different process

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

First Doubt :- Do we need to create TranscationScope for Select sql statements?
From my ASP.NET MVC application I am trying to insert the content in one table using TranscationalScope. I put a break point in the code just before calling ExecuteNonQuery(), and opened a SQL Server Management Studio, and executed one select* from table;  query, but it did not wait and executed immediately.
Ideally TranscationScope used to put a lock on the table , but I didn't see that.

Additionally I wrote one console application(Instead of using SQL Server Management Studio) and executed same select query using TranscationScope, but there also it executed immediately without any wait, and my break point is still active in my ASP.NET web application.

Below is code which I wrote in ASP.NET application.

```
public void UpdateBranchDetails()
    {
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE BranchDetails
                    SET 

              [Reviews] = " + Reviews.ToString() + @"
              ,[Overall_Satisfaction] = " + Overall_Satisfaction.ToString() + @"
              ,[Goods_Condition_At_Delivery] = " + Goods_Condition_At_Delivery.ToString() + @"
              ,[Staff_Behaviour] = " + Staff_Behaviour.ToString() + @"
              ,[Timeliness] = " + Timeliness.ToString() + @"
              ,[Packaging_And_Loading_Professionalism] = " + Packaging_And_Loading_Professionalism.ToString() + @"
              ,[Likelihood_To_Recommned] = " + Likelihood_To_Recommned.ToString() + @"

                WHERE BranchID = " + BranchID.ToString(), sqlConn);
                sqlConn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                ts.Complete();
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

In the above mentioned code sqlConn, is the object of SqlConneciton class and being declared as a class member.

Comment: TransactionScope does not create locks on table directly, it creates a transaction (if required and there's none ambient). Not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to consider is that creating a new `TransactionScope` with the parameterless constructor doesn't always create a database transaction. If calling code has already created a `TransactionScope`, it will use that one (they call this the ambient transaction).

Second thing to consider is the [isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms679234.aspx). This determines the type of concurrency the database will allow.

The default [isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms679234.aspx) is `ISOLATIONLEVEL_SERIALIZABLE`. 
Which will lock any write operation on data that has been read by a concurrent transaction.

In your example, you need to tell the database what kind of concurrency you require on the data you have read.

```
-- I require all access to the data I query in this transaction to be serialized
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM [YourTable]
```

Then execute your code. You will notice that the `ExecuteNonQuery()` call will stall, until you either `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` the transaction you started above.

Comment: I tried changing the constructor to TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required), which is any how set to true by default. But still I am seeing that select sql query is passing without wait, from either SQL Server or my console application

Comment: To be clear TransactionScope does NOT enforce a lock on the table. It all depends the isolation you set. Are you setting the Isolation level in your query in SQL Management Studio and starting a transaction?

Comment: yes I have set the isolation level as SERIALIZABLE. but not help. What I would like to achieve is, when I am updating/inserting records in a table from my website code, then at that time if somebody is trying to read the data from the same table then he should not end up reading dirty data. I would like to have some kind of sync between read and write on the same table.

Comment: Describe exactly what you have done so far, and expected to see. Because if you either read or write to a record in serializable isolation mode, a write from a different thread will wait until completion

Answer (score 0):

I could able to see that my select sql query is waiting for the transaction to complete.  Actually in my code where I was inserting the content in the row, I did not execute ExecuteNonQuery() method. I just entered in the transactionScope and put the break point. I was under the assumption that by just entering the TransactionScope it locks the rows to prevent dirty read. But this was wrong, ideally we have to issue DML cmd to SQL server then only it locks the record till we commit the transaction...

Comment: Before you execute something how is SQL Server supposed to know what you will be accessing?